# Python Loop, Need to / Can't Retain Value from Original Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm attempting to loop through groups of phrases to match and score them among all the members in each group. Even if some of the phrases are the same, they may have different Codes which is what I'm trimming from the loop inputs - but need to retain in the final `df2`. I have to make the comparison in the loop without the code but the issue is tying it back to the original df that contains the code so I can identify which rows need to be flagged.

The code below works but I need to add the original `DESCR` to df2. Appending a and b only contains the trim.

I've tried `df.at[]` but have mixed, incorrect results. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz as fz
import itertools

data = [[1,'Oneab'],[1,'Onebc'],[1,'Twode'],[2,'Threegh'],[2,'Threehi'],[2,'Fourjk'],[3,'Fivekl'],[3,'Fivelm'],[3,'Fiveyz']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Ids','DESCR'])

n_list = []
a_list = []
b_list = []
pr_list = []
tsr_list = []

groups = df.groupby('Ids')
for n,g in groups:
    for a, b in itertools.product(g['DESCR'].str[:-2],g['DESCR'].str[:-2]):
        if str(a) < str(b):
            try:
                n_list.append(n)
                a_list.append(a)
                b_list.append(b)
                pr_list.append(fz.partial_ratio(a,b))
                tsr_list.append(fz.token_set_ratio(a,b))
            except:
                pass
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': n_list, 'First Comparator': a_list, 'Second Comparator': b_list, 'Partial Ratio': pr_list, 'Token Set Ratio': tsr_list})
```

Instead of:

```
ab bc 50 50
ab de 0 0
bc de 0 0
gh hi 50 50
gh jk 0 0
hi jk 50 50
...
```

I'd like to see:

```
Oneab Onebc 50 50
Oneab Twode 0 0
Onebc Twode 0 0
Threegh Threehi 50 50
Threegh Fourjk 0 0
Threehi Fourjk 50 50
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into a similar issue - figured it out - instead of filtering the inputs at the beginning of the second level loop, I'm bringing the full value into the second loop and stripping it there:

```
a2 = a[6:]
b2 = b[6:]
```

So:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz as fz
import itertools

data = [[1,'Oneab'],[1,'Onebc'],[1,'Twode'],[2,'Threegh'],[2,'Threehi'],[2,'Fourjk'],[3,'Fivekl'],[3,'Fivelm'],[3,'Fiveyz']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Ids','DESCR'])

n_list = []
a_list = []
b_list = []
pr_list = []
tsr_list = []

groups = df.groupby('Ids')
for n,g in groups:
    for a, b in itertools.product(g['DESCR'],g['DESCR']):
        if str(a) < str(b):
            try:
                a2 = a[:-2]
                b2 = b[:-2]
                n_list.append(n)
                a_list.append(a)
                b_list.append(b)
                pr_list.append(fz.partial_ratio(a2,b2))
                tsr_list.append(fz.token_set_ratio(a2,b2))
            except:
                pass
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': n_list, 'First Comparator': a_list, 'Second Comparator': b_list, 'Partial Ratio': pr_list, 'Token Set Ratio': tsr_list})
```